# Proof and intuitive explanation of properties of distribution function?

Tags: probability, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

My textbook doesn't go much into why they are true and the intuition behind these properties:

1) $F(-\infty) = 0$

2) $F(\infty) = 1$

3) $F$ is a non-decreasing function of $y$

Can someone elaborate on these properties and explain the reasoning behind them?

Comment: They are all rather immediate consequences of the [axioms of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) (and nearly equivalent to them): consider consulting them before you go any further with this.  You will likely discover the answers yourself.

Comment: Axiom 3 looks useful for 1) and 2), but I'm not seeing the dots connecting. Could you give a more explicit explanation?

Comment: If the cdf ever decreased some probability would have to be negative or the density would have to drop below zero.

Comment: Express each of the events *in words* and think what those are ... 1.what's the probability that a random variable is less than or equal to $-\infty$?  2. Ditto, but with $\infty$. 3. Similarly state in words the events you're computing the probability for in $F(y)$ and $F(y')$ for $y'>y$. Now consider the event $y<Y\leq y'$. Can its probability ever be negative?

Comment: 1) B/c all events have to be equal or greater than zero, so there's 0 chance any event is less than 0?

Comment: 2) B/c all events sum up to 1, any one event can be at most 1, which is less than infinity, so the probability that any event is smaller than infinity is 100%? 3) This one I really don't get